# Orbital speed in an elliptic orbit

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, satellites

I want to have a general solution for calculating orbits. Wikipedia says how to put object on circle orbit. We must give it speed $v_1 = \sqrt{g(h_o +R)}  $ Where $h_o$ - is the orbit height, and $R$ - Earth radius.

But how to calculate the speed that the object must have, if we want to place it in an elliptical orbit?

For example:

Having massive massive spherical object with mass $M$ and radius $R$.

which speed $V$ we must to give to this object to put it on elliptical orbit with eccentricity $\epsilon = E$ , and perihelium $P$?

Comment: Well. This could be a duplicate, but on my level of understanding physics and language it's too hard to make assumptions of such kind. Furthermore, given answer is very good in understanding.

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate. The proposed duplicate question addresses the concept of the shape of the orbit but doesn't address the concept of orbital velocity at all. The [vis viva equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) is the answer to Vasiliy's question. Since that's part of the accepted answer, reopening is not particularly important. But still, this question should not have been closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using energy conservation. It holds

\begin{equation}
-\frac{GMm}{P}+\frac{1}{2}mV^2 = - \frac{GMm}{2a},
\end{equation}

where $a$ is the semimajor axis and related to $P$ by $P=a(1-\epsilon)$. You can understand the RHS from Virial's theorem, for instance.

You may also want to check out the vis-viva equation.

psm.

Comment: What does RHS stands for?

Comment: Right hand side. :-)

Comment: The correct equation is: \begin{equation}
-\frac{GMm}{P}+\frac{1}{2} \mu V^2 = - \frac{GMm}{2a},
\end{equation}. Where $\mu$ is the reduced mass.